# Mongodb - I need to delete multiple objects from array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I have this data set:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6036953aec9d2a3612452bae"), "name" : "Chris",
        "friends" : [
                      { "name" : "xyz", "age" : 23 }, // delete
                      { "name" : "xyz", "age" : 34 }, // delete
                      { "name" : "abc", "age" : 18 },
                      { "name" : "pqr", "age" : 27 } // delete
                    ],
}
```

I want to delete the mentioned objects for the user:

This is the query I am making:

```js
db.users.updateOne(
  { name: "Chris" }, 
  { $pull: { 'friends.$[el]' } }, 
  { arrayFilters: [{ 'el.name': { $in: [ 'xyz', 'abc' ] } }] }  
)
```

> Error:

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after property id :
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) into the section **Remove Items from an Array of Documents** where is an example for what you want.

This query works:

```
db.users.updateOne(
{"name": "Chris"},
{
  "$pull": {
    "friends": {
      "name": {
        "$in": ["xyz","pqr"]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oyqgFtS8Hd_)

This query update the first document found where `name` is `Chris` and remove (`$pull`) objects where `friends.name` is into the `$in` array.